# Obtain 1000 confidence interval from t.test

Tags: r, function, loops

```
x <- c(1:100)
y <- c(89:300)
s1 <- sample(x, 30)
s2 <- sample(y, 30)
mytest <- t.test(s1, s2)
mytest$conf.int
```

I would like to run this 1000 times and create a matrix with the 1000 intervals obtained. I have tried some loops but every time I am getting the same 1000 intervals. However, every time it should give me a different interval since I am sampling each time before performing the t.test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `replicate`:

```
x <- c(1:100)
y <- c(89:300)

myCI = function(x,y) {
  s1 <- sample(x, 30)
  s2 <- sample(y, 30)
  mytest <- t.test(s1, s2)
  mytest$conf.int
}

CIs = t(replicate(1000, myCI(x,y)))
```